# custom label not being filled with data completely

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
 if (product) {

    if ([product.title isStringOfInterest]) {

        scriptName = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:@"" font:[PPFonts bold20] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];

        [self.topContainerContent addObject:scriptName];

        extraName = [[PPLinearLayoutLabelItem alloc] initWithText:@"" font:[PPFonts regular14] maxWidth:[LayoutValues getMaxWidthClipped]];
        [scriptName setPaddingTop:20];


        [self.topContainerContent addObject:extraName];
        }
      }

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^(void){
    [self loadProductDetails];
    });



-(void) loadProductDetails{
    IHProduct *product = orderDisplayed.product;
    id<ProductDownloadServiceProtocol> productDetailsDownloader = [[ProductDownloadService alloc] initWithClient:[[HttpClient alloc] initWith:APIbackend forEndpoint:EndpointProduct]];


    [productDetailsDownloader downloadProductWithProductID:product.productID success:^(ProductDownloadResponse *response) {

    scriptName.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",response.product.title,response.product.pillTypeShort];
    extraName.label.text =  response.product.sameAs;

    NSString *qtyText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ PACKS (%@ at $%@ per pack)",[orderDisplayed.interval objectForKey:@"quantity_per_interval"], [orderDisplayed.interval objectForKey:@"quantity_per_interval"], response.product.price];

    quantity.label.text = qtyText;
    } error:^(ProductDownloadResponse *response) {
        [self hideHttpLoadingOverlay];
        [RMUniversalAlert showAlertInViewController:self
                                          withTitle:alertErrorTitle
                                            message:@"Error downloading mail order product details"
                                  cancelButtonTitle:OKDialogButton     
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil
                                           tapBlock:nil];
        }];
}
```

The labels `extraname` and `scriptname` are getting filled or getting chopped off in the end i.e. incomplete data. How can I fix this? When I statically put large texts in this the data gets filled into those views nicely. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish adjust width of UILabel based on it text content then use below code;

```
NSDictionary *fontAttributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14]};
CGRect rectOfText = [textToMeasure boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                            options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                         attributes:fontAttributes
                                            context:nil];
CGRect tempFrame = self.label.frame;
tempFrame.size.width = rectOfText.size.width;
self.label.frame = tempFrame;
```

And if you wish to change its font based on uilabel width then use below;
NOTE : This will work only if self.label.numberOfLines = 1.

```
self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
self.label.minimumFontSize = 0;
```

Comment: Can I do all of this from within my loadproductdetails i.e. dispatch thread or do I have to set up my label as you suggest initially so that the api call fills it with data later on?

Comment: PS what is rectOfText? fontAttributes?

Comment: I have corrected code!! For Now (testing purpose) adding then in loadproductdetails!! @Ackman

Comment: You should not be updating your UI any other than main thread! Afterwards do add code to make change label through main thread!

Comment: Thanks @nickdange_me :) it did the job now!